# Download prerequisite from the following location in window installer of VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I want to download prerequisite from the my server location. I am using VS 2013.
we have three option to download prerequisite.

1. Download prerequisite from the component vendor's website.
2. Download prerequisite from the same location as my application
3. Download prerequisite from the following location

I want to go with 3rd option.

When i try with third option than i get this error:
"Error  1   To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'DotNetFX451\NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe' for item 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 (x86 and x64)' to your local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=239883.    D:\Projects...VersionSetup.vdproj  DetectFrameworkVersionSetup
"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can find multiple directory inside the path : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows
Like v7.0A, v7.1A, v8.0, v8.0A, v8.1, v8.1A....

Bootstrapper packages at : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper\Packages

Series 7 used for the .net version 2010 and 
Series 8 used for the .net version 2013

If you are preparing setup project in VS 2013 and want to download prerequisites with

2. Download prerequisite from the same location as my application
3. Download prerequisite from the following location

than setup project search for the bootstrapper file in side that folder.

i.e :
if i select .net framework 4.5 as a prerequisites than setup project find the .net framework 4.5 exe file in side the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX45".

So just copy appropriate exe file inside "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper\Packages\" and try to build project.

Comment: Can you explain this answer more?